# what is a meaning of inclearing check that has remained outstanding for escheated accounts?

Tags: banking

**What is a meaning of in-clearing check that has remained outstanding for Escheated accounts?**

Comment: What country, can you give some more context

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on State/Country laws. Some States/Countries have laws that amounts on outstanding but not cashed checks would be transferred to a government custodian until they're claimed, if they're not claimed within a certain period.

For example, [in California](https://ucpi.sco.ca.gov/UCP/) if your check is not cashed within 3 years, you're expected to transfer the amount to the State's controller's office.